# Example of infinte disconnected space

Tags: general-topology

I need an Example of infinite disconnected space which has finite number of connected components 
other than the punctured real line?

Comment: Puncture two points on the real line! Or take out the axes from the coordinate plane, or remove the equator from a sphere(in any dimension, and so on.

Comment: very good but we are still in the same area of removing points or line segments  (i.e subsets) any way thank you

Comment: *every* space $X$ can be obtained from some other space $Y$ by removing points. Simply add points to $X$ to obtain $Y$ .... and you can always do that in a way such that $Y$ is connected.

Answer (score 2):

Any topological space described in your question can be written as: $$X=\sqcup_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$$ (disjoint union, coproduct), where:

1) $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$.

2) Each $X_{i}$ is connected.

3) At least one of the topological spaces $X_{i}$ is infinite.

Here the $X_i$ identified as subspaces of $X$ are the components, so $n$ is the number of its components.

Example:

$S$ is an infinite set with $x\notin S$ and topological
space $X$ has $S\cup\left\{ x\right\} $ as underlying set and $\mathcal{O}=\left\{ \emptyset,\left\{ x\right\} ,S,S\cup\left\{ x\right\} \right\} $
as topology.